# Section transition in SwiftUI Form

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui

The `Section` transition in `Form` is always left-right, I would like to change it to right-left in some cases, I tried `.transition` with `.move` modifier, but it does not have effect.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var visible = true

    var body: some View {
        
        Form {
            Button("visible") {
                self.visible.toggle()
            }
            visible ? Section {
                Text("Section 1")
                Text("Section 1")
            }.transition(.move(edge: .leading)) : nil
            !visible ? Section {
                Text("Section 2")
                Text("Section 2")
            }.transition(.move(edge: .trailing)) : nil
            Section {
                Text("Section 3")
                Text("Section 3")
            } // Section 3 should not be animated
        }.animation(.linear(duration: 0.5))
        
    }
}
```

Comment: any solution? i am also having problems with animatic sections in forms

Comment: @memical I ended up using two `Form` in an `HStack`

Answer (score 1):

I read through a significant amount of Apple's code documentation for SwiftUI forms and it appears that there are very few options for customization; specifically with the way you have the code currently set up. In that, I would recommend creating the animations and page from scratch. Doing it that way, you would have complete creative freedom of the directions for the transitions. This would take a lot of work to look like a Form, but it's possible. The following answer will give you a right-left transition: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62144939/13296047